# Cinemachine 2D Not working as it should be

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, cinemachine

When my player jumps the camera follows the player perctly (Btw I got the x dead zone activted with 0.5) but when the player falls, the camera doesn't follow it.
[cinemachines2D settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVf6G.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post a screenshot of your cinemachine settings? And what do you mean by falling? Do you mean that when a player jumps, the camera follows up fine, but when he falls down the camera stays up? That could be related to where the center of your player(followed object) is and your Y dead zone setting in cinemachine.

Comment: Thtats exactly what happens to me. I've just posted the screenshot with the settings.

Comment: First maybe try smaller deadzone height value like 0.1 and see how it behaves and then maybe try to add some y offset to Tracked Object Offset to correct offset for your player.